# What is the difference between this and this.root inside a Polymer element

Tags: polymer

The developers guide for Polymer says you need to use this.root to access the element that is being defined.  But looking in the Chrome development tools this also seems to point at the element.

What is the difference.  Is there something subtle that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in an element declaration scope means the element itself. `this.root` refers to the shadow root of the element (if it is there).

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the shadow root is the one not yet stamped into the main document?.  The reason I am asking is that I am contemplating how to do routing, and my solution involves a route controller traversing the dom tree as eventually instantiated, downwards through all the nested elements looking for route marker elements and noting their relative positions of their parents in the hierarchy (complex I know, but its an idea I am experimenting with.).  I want to make sure I start at the right place looking for my children, placed their by using the content tag in my template.